# Antlr parser not happening

Tags: javascript, antlr4

If I have a test grammer TestGrammar.g4,

```
grammar TestGrammar;

startRule : compilationUnit EOF;

compilationUnit
   : programUnit*
   ;

programUnit
  : execSqlStatement
  ;

execSqlStatement
  : EXEC SQL EXECSQLLINE+ END_EXEC DOT?
  ;

freeText
   //: ~NL*
   : STRING+
   ;

EXECSQLLINE : EXECSQLTAG WS ~('\n' | '\r' | '}')* ('\n' | '\r' | '}');

EXECSQLTAG : '*>EXECSQL';

END_EXEC : E N D '-' E X E C;
EXEC : E X E C;
SQL : S Q L;

// symbols
STRING  : .+?;
NL      : '\r'? '\n' | '\r';
//NEWLINE : '\r'? '\n' -> channel(HIDDEN);
DOT : '.';
WS : [ \t\f;]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

with an input a simple text in it ,

```
  const input = `
  EXEC SQL
    somethig goes here
  END-EXEC.
`
```

and if I run this data I have obtained Abstract syntax tree(AST) and it seems not to be parsed completly,

```
programUnit
          (
            execSqlStatement EXEC   SQL   \n s o m e t h i g   g o e s   h e r e \n s o m e t h i g   g o e s   h e r e \n END-EXEC
          )
```

expected output to be

```
 (
  startRule
  (
    compilationUnit
    (
      programUnit
      (
         execSqlStatement EXEC SQL
  (
    freeText
    (
      something goes here
    )
  )
  (
    END EXEC
  )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

since it has to parse content inside `execSqlStatement` which I'm not able to retrieve .
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

A few things here:

1. ANTLR4 doesn't produce syntax trees (AST), but parse trees. An AST is made of the input symbols that were matched in a (more or less) tree like fashion. A parse tree is made of parse context nodes, which describe the path in the grammar that matched. They also contain the symbols that matched, so they are kind of a superset of ASTs.
2. Your grammar is not complete, e.g. it misses the definitions for the rules `S`, `Q`, `E`, `X` etc. Examples in questions should be self contained and be transformable without extra adjustments.
3. You never use your rule `freeText`. How can it contribute to the output then?
4. You coded the entire SQL code into the single lexer rule `EXECSQLLINE`. Of course this will appear as a single lexer token in the output. If that's your intention then ok, but usually one wants to get hold of the individual parts of a query.

Comment: Mike can you please help me get "but usually one wants to get hold of the individual parts of a query." in elaborated answer please ...

Comment: I would recommend that we finish this question first and you ask a specific follow up question if needed.